# Symfony: how to pass Monolog with a different name to services created by a bundle

Tags: symfony, logging, dependency-injection

In my bundle I'd like to pass an instance of `Logger` with a custom name.

Until now, I needed this logger only in one service, and so I did this:

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger = null)
{
    $this->logger = $logger instanceof Logger ? $logger->withName('StripeBundle') : $logger;
}
```

This way I change the name of the `Logger` and get a new instance of it.

The problem now is that I need this Logger to be used also by a controller.

So, following this path, in my controller I should do something like this:

```
public function notifyAction(Request $request)
{
    $logger = $this->get('logger')->withName('StripeBundle');
}
```

This is duplication.

Instead, I'd like to create a service called something like `stripe_bundle.logger` that is an exact copy of the `Logger` created by Symfony, BUT with a different name.

Now, how can I do this?

I've started approach the problem using a `CompilerPass` but how can I do this? With a simple `clone`?

```
class LoggerCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        /** @var Definition $loggerDefinition */
        $loggerDefinition = $container->findDefinition('logger');
        $loggerDefinition->addMethodCall('withName', ['StripeBundle']);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the `withName` method returns a new cloned instance of the `Logger` with the name changed.

How can I assign it to a new service?